# VirtualBox: Use scrcpy on Windows 10 guest

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora, tablet

My host is Fedora 34 Workstation.

My guest is Windows 10.

I have a tablet (Samsung Galaxy Note).

I would like to use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to mirror my tablet on the Windows 10 guest.

Is that possible?

I connect my tablet to my Fedora 34 Worstation, but VirtualBox does not recognize it.

When I start my Windows 10 guest, the Devices->USB menu shows no entry. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Is it possible to mirror my tablet on the Windows 10 guest using scrcpy?

EDIT: `scrcpy` works fine on the Fedora 34 Worstation host

Comment: That mode has been removed and pretty much unavailable since somewhere around Android 4

Comment: For a good description of MTP and USB Mass Storage you should have a look at https://superuser.com/a/1131661/19943

Comment: scrcpy uses ADB for device communication. Hence it has absolutely nothing to do with MTP and I don't see how the duplicate questions can match here.

Comment: @Robert me neither, I think it should work, maybe I phrased the question badly

Comment: I rephrased the question, can we re-open it?

Comment: In my opinion you first have to solve the Fedora-VirtualBox problem that no USB device is shown. This should be independent from the guest. As I don't have Fedora experience I don't know what do do, I can only recommend to you to test on Fedora if ADB access is possible.

Comment: @Robert scrcpy works without problems on Fedora